# A little question on rationals and open sets in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Let $A$ be an open set of real numbers, and $D$ be the set of rationals in $A$. For every $d\in D$, let $J(d)$ be an (arbitrary) open interval such that $d \in J(d) \subseteq A$. Is it true that $\bigcup \{J (d) | d \in D\} = A$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't true.

Consider $A=(0,1)$ and $J(d)$ being whichever one of $(0,\frac1\pi)$ or $(\frac1\pi,1)$ which contains $d$.

Comment: And if we were to impose J(d) = (d-1/n,d+1/n) for some n = 1,2,... ?

Comment: @Alex still no. List the rationals in $(0,1)$ as $d_1,d_2,\ldots$, and let $J(d_k)=(d_k-\frac{1}{2^{k+2}},d_k+\frac{1}{2^{k+2}})$. Then the combined width of all the $J(d_k)$'s is $\frac12$, so even with no overlap, (and no "overspill", as in $J(d_k)\not\subseteq (0,1)$), half of $A$ (as measured by, well, _measure_) is still uncovered. In fact, this still works for $A=\Bbb R$, meaning by far most of the number line is uncovered. We can also adjust the exponent to make the sum of the widths as small as we want.